# Why does PayPal rely on bank card to send money to friend instead of using my bank account?

Tags: money-transfer, paypal, france

My PayPal account is linked to my bank account and the Mastercard that's linked to it. Both are verified and work fine when I use PayPal to purchase goods from the Net.

Last night, I wanted to pay back a friend through PayPal, and noticed that, at least when using the Android application, PayPal insists on fetching the money indirectly through the Mastercard I added instead of withdrawing the money directly from the bank account to which the Mastercard is linked.

Unsurprisingly, using the bank card involves a fee.

Is this due to the fact that my PayPal balance is currently empty? In that case, why doesn't PayPal simply withdraw money directly from my bank account for free instead?

Thank you.

---

Edit: I can confirm that, when the PayPal balance is empty and we wish to send money to a friend, PayPal doesn't give users the option of fetching money transparently and for free from the bank account that is linked to the PayPal account; Instead, it forces users to use the bank card linked to it (provided there is one, obviously) and imposes a transaction fee.

As to why it doesn't simply fetch the money directly and for free from the bank account like it does when paying a vendor on the Internet is anybody's guess…

Comment: What country are you in? Paypal rules are per country.

Comment: France. PayPal does say withdrawing money from a bank account is free: www.paypal.com/fr/webapps/mpp/paypal-fees